# I'm trying to send an email from Django using Gmail SMTP

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I've set insecure source ON in my account's setting. Also, this is my settings.py file. Can anybody help me?

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com '
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER =' my email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
```

and I'm getting this error in terminal when I write this code

```
PS D:\start here\silicium7\config-project> python manage.py sendtestemail atabarzega79@gmail.com 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
   main()
 File "manage.py", line 18, in main
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\sendtestemail.py", line 33, in handle
   recipient_list=kwargs['email'],
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
   return mail.send()
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
   return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
   new_conn_created = self.open()
 File "D:\start here\silicium7\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 62, in open
   self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
 File "C:\Users\Ata Barzegar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
   (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
 File "C:\Users\Ata Barzegar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
   self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
 File "C:\Users\Ata Barzegar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
   self.source_address)
   for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
 File "C:\Users\Ata Barzegar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
   for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is may be useful for you.

Add **DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL** in **settings.py** and test it through python shell:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com '
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='realmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '**********'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testmail@gmail.com'
```

**Run python shell**:

```py
python manage.py shell
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

subject = 'Some subject'
from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL   
message = 'This is my test message'
recipient_list = ['mytestmail@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com']           
html_message = '<h1>This is my HTML test</h1>'
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, html_message=html_message)
```

If output code is `1` then email sent successfully....

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I need to update my EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, cause I changed the EMAIL_HOST_USER. But there is a problem when I tryed to send recipient's email from another mail service (not gmail). I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I put it "user.email_user(subject, message)" it works. I haven't email_user anymore...